# Suggesstions on NOSQL DB with a good stable C++ client

Tags: c++, database, nosql

I want to try hooking up my pet project to a NOSQL type DB as eventually it will need to be able to process a large data volume with a very simple data structure...pretty much ideal for NOSQL.

However I am using C++ and have 0 interest in writing a wrapper around a C client. I googled some to try and find examples for using Cassandra with a C++ client and didn't find much.

So my requirements are: Free, Runs on Windows, Good C++ client with examples available that don't assume I am already a NOSQL / Thrift guru.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Redis has clients for most major programming languages, including C++.  Everything I've been hearing is that Redis is the new hotness in NoSQL.

The thing about Redis (and memcached) is that they ultimately provide telnet-like interfaces.  If you can open a socket to localhost and send commands, you can use the NoSQL database.  That's more or less what Rediska (Redis PHP Client) does under the hood.

You should be able to whip up a dumb get-set interface in a few hours, and implement the remaining interfaces in a day or so.

Comment: My issue with Redis is that it doesn't run on Windows...I see some people have unofficial minwn or cygwin ports, but my main dev environment is windows and I don't want to have to set of a linux VM on every machine I want to develop on. Seems painful.

Comment: I grabbed a build somewhere, seems to work fine on my Win7 box except for some config file weirdness.  I think I used this version: https://github.com/dmajkic/redis/downloads